# CSS snippet not working on IE :before/:after

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a heading with lines on both sides.
For some reason it doesn't work on IE only on the left side.

http://jsfiddle.net/1qp9dvuL/

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
h2:before,
h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  content: '\a0';
  background-color: red;
}
h2:before {
  margin-left: -55%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h2>THE HEADING</h2>
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: sorry, it's 11.0.96xx

Comment: Its a very useful plugin, use this https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: I see what you mean, IE11 is ignoring the override. Investigating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution that works in Chrome/FF/IE

Here is an alternative work-around that works for content/text with varying widths.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3johg5gh/)

The reason it wasn't work in IE was because the pseudo elements weren't being positioned relative to the text. To work around that, I removed the absolute positioning from the pseudo elements, and set the `display` to `table-cell` so that they are positioned relative to the text.

Adjust the `right`/`left` positioning to control the space around the text.

```css
.line {
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.line:before,
.line:after {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
  width: 45%;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f00;
}
.line:before {
  right: 5%;
}
.line:after {
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="line">THE HEADING</h2>

<h2 class="line">THE LONGER HEADING</h2>
```